# move textview on touch within screen and toast on double tap android

Tags: android, textview, touch, gesturelistener

I am new in android . I have one TextView that should be moved on touch with in entire screen and I also want double tap event with TextView. I know how to move on touch and I also get double tab event using GestureListener but I dont know how to merge that code because when I double tap on textview it also call action down event.

```
  private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

                // event when double tap occurs
                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

                    return true;
                }
            }

    tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

                    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
                }
```

This way I can achieve double tap using touch method. And below touch method for move `TextView`.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

     switch(event.getAction())
                     {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        {
                            //some code
                          break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        {
                            // some code
                          break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        {
                      // some code
                         break;
                        }
                     }
                    return true;
                }
```

But how can I merge both touch event and achieve touch on move as well as double tap.

Answer (score 0):

may this help

```
boolean flag = false;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            flag = flase;//on move
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            // some code
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (flag == true) {
                //double tap event
            }
            flag = true;//first tap
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```